# Evaluate $\lim_{x \to -2} \frac{x + 2}{\sin(\frac{\pi x}{2})}$ using continuity (without L'Hospital)

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity, limits-without-lhopital

> A little background: I am TAing for a Calculus I class (mostly non-math majors), and this problem showed up on the worksheet for tomorrow. We have fully developed limits, including the squeeze theorem, and continuity, but we have not covered L'Hospital's rule yet. I am not sure how the students are supposed to approach this one. Perhaps I am missing something. Here is the problem:

Use continuity to evaluate the limit. Explain your answer (especially why you can use continuity).

$$
\lim_{x \to -2} \frac{x + 2}{\sin\big(\frac{\pi x}{2}\big)}.
$$

---

> We see that this function is not continuous (has a hole) at $-2$ and, for that matter, at all values of $x$ that make $\sin\big(\frac{\pi x}{2}\big) = 0$. We will get $\frac{0}{0}$ if we do all the steps to get down to the point at which we can just plug in $-2$. We cannot use L'Hospital's rule. The best direction I see is something like this:
> \begin{align*}
> \lim_{x \to -2} \frac{x + 2}{\sin\big(\frac{\pi x}{2}\big)} &= \lim_{x \to -2} \frac{x}{\sin\big(\frac{\pi x}{2}\big)} + \lim_{x \to -2} \frac{2}{\sin\big(\frac{\pi x}{2}\big)}\\
> &= \frac{2}{\pi}\lim_{x \to -2} \frac{\frac{\pi x}{2}}{\sin\big(\frac{\pi x}{2}\big)} + 2\lim_{x \to -2} \frac{1}{\sin\big(\frac{\pi x}{2}\big)}
> \end{align*}
> From there, we might be able to do some $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$-type thing with the left term, but I am not quite sure what to do with the right term.

Comment: The first equality works if the individual limits exist and are finite.

Comment: True. I'm guessing that the left one does exist, but I think the second does not. By L'Hospital's, the answer is $\frac{-2}{\pi}$ I think.

Comment: Hint: $\sin (\frac {\pi x} 2)=-\sin (\pi +\frac {\pi x} 2) \sim - (\pi +\frac {\pi x} 2) $ as $ x \to -2$. The answer is $-\frac 2 {\pi}$.

Comment: You may be able to turn the thing inside such that you can directly use $\sin x = x$ as $x\to0$.

Comment: You are splitting the limit of an indeterminate form into two limits which are not indeterminate, which is probably not helpful.  Try substituting $ \ u \ = \ x + 2 \ $ , use the properties of the sine function to write it as $ \ -\sin(\pi/2 · u) \ $ and use the limit law for $ \ \frac{\sin u}{u} \ $ as $ \ u \rightarrow 0 \ $ appropriately.

Comment: 1 - squeeze theorem? 2 - are you allowed the thing for $\frac{\sin(u)}{u}$? I think there's a substitution to make here

Comment: I really don't like the statement "We see that this function is not continuous (has a hole) at −2".  The function is not *defined* at $x=-2$.  I generally think that it is inappropriate to talk about whether or not a function is continuous at a point which is not in its domain.  For example, is $\sqrt{x}$ continuous at $-1$?  I think I could make a good argument either way, depending on how, precisely, "continuity" has been defined.  You can't "just plug in $-2$" because the function is *not defined* at $-2$, not because the function is discontinuous there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the right term explodes, and so does the left (because $x\to -2$, the denominator goes to $0$ but the numerator does not). The decomposition performed is therefore incorrect. However,

> The key idea is that $-\sin(\pi+x)= \sin x$ for any $x$. This is fairly obvious to prove from the addition formula.

In particular, we have :
$$
\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right) = -\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{2} + \pi\right) = - \sin\left(\frac{\pi (x+2)}{2}\right)
$$

Now, the advantage we have is that we can make use of the $\sin x \over x$ rule, after a change of variable. Indeed, we have :
$$
\frac{x+2}{\sin(\frac{\pi x}{2})} = -\frac{x+2}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi(x+2)}2\right)} = -\frac{2}{\pi} \frac{\frac{\pi(x+2)}{2}}{\sin \left(\frac{\pi(x+2)}{2}\right)}
$$

Let $y = \frac{\pi(x+2)}{2}$. Then, as $x \to -2$ we have $y \to 0$. In particular, $$
\lim_{x \to -2} \frac{x+2}{\sin(\frac{\pi x}{2})} = \lim_{y \to 0} -\frac 2{\pi} \frac{y}{\sin(y)} = \boxed{-\frac{2}{\pi}}
$$

and this can easily be verified from [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+as+x+approaches+-2+of+%28x%2B2%29+%2F+sin%28%28pi+x%29%2F2%29) as well.

Note : Thanks to @lalala below. They mention that $\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{y}{\sin y} = 1$ can be proven through L'Hopital. However, we can do better, and that's why this is a standard result.

I would suggest looking at [this page](https://www.sarthaks.com/591676/prove-that-lim-x0-sinx-x-1) for a geometric proof of the inequality $1 < \frac{y}{\sin y} < \frac 1{\cos y}$ for all $y \in (\frac{-\pi }{2} , \frac \pi 2)$(For $y$ negative note that $\sin y = -\sin (-y)$ has the same sign as $y$ so they cancel out). Then the squeeze theorem applies as $y \to 0$ to conclude.

Comment: This looks great! I am going to work it out myself.

Comment: @TheSenate Thanks for the feedback! I'm used to giving more detailed answers, but in this case I decided not to. Almost all details are provided, except that you must prove that $y \to 0$ when $x \to -2$, which follows from limit-based rules. I hope substitution is applicable, I see "continuity" in the allowed rules, so it should come as part of that.

Comment: I think you should elaborate on the last equality sign (probably you use derivative of sin is cos and inv function in continuous)

Comment: @lalala Hey ,thanks for the comment and apologies that I read it a little late. I was under the impression that the result $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$ is a *standard* result that is proved by methods other than L'Hopital (although, as you mention, it could easily be proven by L'Hopital). The result can be proven in a Calculus class by proving that $\cos x<\frac{\sin x}{x} < 1$ for $x \approx 0$ using areas on a diagram, and using the squeeze theorem. IF not for this, I'dhave to use L'Hopital, so good catch.

Answer (score 1):

We have,

$$\begin{align}\lim_{x \to -2} \frac{x + 2}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)}
&=2\lim_{u \to -\pi} \frac{\frac{\pi +u}{\pi}}{-\sin (\pi +u)}\\
&=-2\lim_{u \to -\pi} \frac{\frac{1}{\pi}}{\frac{\sin (\pi +u)}{\pi +u}}\\
&=-\frac {2}{\pi}.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

In theses cases a change of coordinates can help, notably by $y=x+2\to 0$ using that $\sin (-\pi + \theta)=-\sin(\theta)$ and standard limits we obtain

$$\lim_{x \to -2} \frac{x + 2}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)}=\lim_{y \to 0} \frac{y}{\sin\left(-\pi +\frac{\pi y}{2}\right)}=\lim_{y \to 0} \left(-\frac 2 \pi\right)\cdot \frac{\frac \pi 2y}{\sin\left( \frac{\pi y}{2}\right)}=-\frac 2 \pi$$